# Проблема с конструктором с параметрами

Tags: c++, классы

При попытке создать объект pc конструктором получаю ошибки в 65 строке.

Ошибки:

```
1) E0289    отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "computer::computer", соответствующие списку аргументов 
2) C2664    "computer::computer(computer &&)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [5]" в "char *"
```

Передаю все параметры, вроде, правильно. Но всё равно есть проблема. Как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class screen {
public:
    screen(char* t, long c, int x, int y) {
        strcpy(type, t);
        colors = c;
        x_resolution = x;
        y_resolution = y;
    }
    void show_screen(void);
private:
    char type[30];
    long colors;
    int x_resolution;
    int y_resolution;
};
void screen::show_screen(void) {
    cout << "Тип экрана: " << type << endl;
    cout << "Количество цветов: " << colors << endl;
    cout << "Распределительная способность: " << x_resolution << " x " << y_resolution << " y " << endl;
}
class mother_board {
public: 
    mother_board(int p, int s, int r) {
        processor = p;
        speed = s;
        RAM = r;
    }
    void show_mother_board();
private:
    int processor;
    int speed;
    int RAM;
};
void mother_board::show_mother_board(void) {
    cout << "Процессор: " << processor << endl;
    cout << "Частота: " << speed << endl;
    cout << "ОЗУ: " << RAM << " Мб" << endl;
}
class computer : public screen, public mother_board {
public: 
    computer(char* n, int h, float f, char* s, long c, int x, int y, int p, int sp, int r) : screen(s, c, x, y), mother_board(p, sp, r) {
        strcpy(name, n);
        hard_disc = h;
        floppy = f;
    }
    void show_computer(void);
private:
    char name[50];
    int hard_disc;
    float floppy;
};
void computer::show_computer(void) {
    cout << "Тип компьютера: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Жесткий диск: " << hard_disc << " Мб" << endl;
    cout << "Дискета: " << floppy << " Мб" << endl;
    show_mother_board();
    show_screen();
}

int main()
{
    computer pc("Sony", 1024, 1.44, "SVGA", 64000000, 780, 1024, 686, 66, 1024);

    pc.show_computer();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любой литерал типа `"Sony"` имеет тип const char*(вернее, смотрите комментарий ниже от  `KoVadim`). В аргументах везде добавьте  `const к char*`.

```
computer(const char* n, int h, float f, const char* s, ... )
```

Если не будем говорить о том, что таким классам лучше  не быть...

Comment: `"Sony"` имеет тип `const char[5]`, который может быть преобразован к `const char*`, но не может потерять модификатор `const`.

Comment: @KoVadim, я оговорился, спасибо за замечание